# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when searching with combobox

Tags: java, indexing

i am trying to search records from a table. and I have a JTextField and a Jcombobox to do the searching
so I have this code for JTextField that does a general filtering of the table through sorting

```
private void SearchBoxKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         
     try{
     TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(((DefaultTableModel)expTable.getModel()));
    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(SearchBox.getText()));
    expTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.getMessage();
    }         // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

this works perfectly

and this code for JCobombox which searches only a particular column

```
   String sql = "Select id,expense,bill,month,year from expenses where month='"+combo_expenditure_month.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'";
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    expTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }catch(SQLException ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
     finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
```

the problem is when I use the JtextField for searching and I use the comboBox afterwards, I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7 >= 7
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:496)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:660)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2706)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5721)
```

am thinking the sorting done with the textfield doesn't close properly before the jcombobox code is initialized. please if that's the case, how do I solve the problem

Comment: You left out the actual error message in you stack trace.

Comment: please its been edited now. please help @Markus. I will be gratefull

Comment: Shot in the dark: you're replacing the table model with a new model, but the `TableRowSorter` object is still using the old model object. Try updating the row sorter with the new model, after you replaced the model in `expTable`.

Comment: ok thanks. am still a new bee in programming. can you please give me a sample code example @Markus.